# iptables: having a context for rules

Tags: iptables

I am looking for a way to get a context/status in iptables-rules. I am not talking about he context of a session here (new, established, ...).

E.g.

```
Request to port 80                  => PASS + set CONTEXT to 1
Request to port 88 and CONTEXT is 1 => PASS
```

So a mechanism that is a sort of simple memory of the past.

Is that possible with an existing extension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`recent`](https://manpages.debian.org/iptables/iptables-extensions.8#recent) match (which as an `iptables` match is quite non-standard: it can be used either to check or to alter the information) could be used for your purpose:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -m recent --set --name contextA -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 88 -m recent --rcheck --name contextA -j ACCEPT
```

Now more plumbing is certainly needed, including the use of options like `--seconds` or additional rules with option `--remove` or the "context" will stay forever set. It all depends on the actual untold goal you're after.

For more complex settings, interfacing `iptables` with [`ipset`](http://ipset.netfilter.org/) using [`set`](https://manpages.debian.org/iptables/iptables-extensions.8#set) match and [`SET`](https://manpages.debian.org/iptables/iptables-extensions.8#SET) target can probably help (it's a superset of `recent`).

If you need this for port knocking, there is a specific [`pknock`](https://manpages.debian.org/xtables-addons-common/xtables-addons.8#pknock) match available with [`xtables-addons`](https://sourceforge.net/projects/xtables-addons/) (which usually requires compiling, since it's coming with external kernel modules), but then also consider tools like [`fwknop`](https://www.cipherdyne.org/fwknop/docs/fwknop-tutorial.html).